# Wakanda Studio encounters port conflict

Tags: wakanda

Newly released Wakanda 2.7.0 Studio reports port 8080 in use (when it is not) when attempting to start the server from Studio with an existing solution.

"Impossible to find or start Wakanda Enterprise Server.  Port 8080 might already be in use by another application.

Wakanda 2.6.0 does not have this issue with the same solution, no changes.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The license for Wakanda Enterprise was not present.  The application does not report not finding a valid license key; rather generates the above cryptic error message.